# Postfix address verification server not working

Tags: debian, postfix

I try to use the [Postfix address verification server](http://www.postfix.org/verify.8.html), but I can’t make it work.

Here is the content of my `main.cf` file, generated by a `postconf -n` command. I mark the four line I modified myself. The other configuration lines come from a fresh debian wheezy installation:

```
address_verify_default_transport = direct_smtp           # added by myself
address_verify_map = btree:/var/lib/postfix/verify_cache # added by myself
address_verify_relayhost =                               # added by myself
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = fake.example.net, localhost.example.net, localhost
myhostname = fake.example.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unverified_recipient   # added by myself
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
```

The verify server is launched. I checked that with  `netstat -l  -p | grep verify` which produces:

```
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1851248  31291/master        private/verify
```

Yet the verify server is never called: when I send an email to a domain which I control the MX server, I can see in the logs of that MX server that the email is sent directly with the right sender address and not "`double-bounce@$myorigin`" as [it should be](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html#limitations). I can also see that no file `/var/lib/postfix/verify_cache` is created.

Here is what I see from my sending server:

```
Dec 18 16:43:07 fake postfix/pickup[19544]: 134A96220474: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 18 16:43:07 fake postfix/cleanup[19633]: 134A96220474: message-id=<20141218154307.134A96220474@fake.example.net>
Dec 18 16:43:07 fake postfix/qmgr[31295]: 134A96220474: from=<root@fake.example.net>, size=447, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 18 16:43:07 fake postfix/smtp[19635]: 134A96220474: to=<realemail@example.net>, relay=fake2.example.net[yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy]:25, delay=0.6, delays=0.09/0/0.13/0.38, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (host fake2.example.net[yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy] said: 450 4.2.0 <realemail@example.net>: Recipient address rejected: Greylisted, see http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/help/example.net.html (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

So, what am I missing to make the Postfix address verification work?

Comment: *Here is the content of my main.cf file, generated by a postconf -d* --> did you mean postconf -n? Parameter `-d` will show the DEFAULT configuration of main.cf, parameter `-n` will show the CHANGES you did in `main.cf`. See [man postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.1.html)

Comment: I changed my text: the right command `postconf -n` and not `postconf -d`, of course. Thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You notice in your maillog snippet

```
Dec 18 16:43:07 fake postfix/pickup[19544]: 134A96220474: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 18 16:43:07 fake postfix/cleanup[19633]: 134A96220474: message-id=<20141218154307.134A96220474@fake.example.net>
Dec 18 16:43:07 fake postfix/qmgr[31295]: 134A96220474: from=<root@fake.example.net>, size=447, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 18 16:43:07 fake postfix/smtp[19635]: 134A96220474: to=<realemail@example.net>, relay=fake2.example.net[yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy]:25, delay=0.6, delays=0.09/0/0.13/0.38, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (host fake2.example.net[yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy] said: 450 4.2.0 <realemail@example.net>: Recipient address rejected: Greylisted, see http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/help/example.net.html (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

there are no `smtpd` word in it.

*Sidenote: In your maillog, email enters postfix pickup process. In [postfix Architecture Overview](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html), there are three ways email will enter postfix: smtpd, qmqpd, or pickup.*

Recipient verification only works when email enters via smtpd (you only define parameter `reject_unverified_recipient` in **smtpd_***_restriction).

And for my case, mail enters from outside server via `smtpd` so it will trigger verify daemon.

Comment: Ok, this explains why it didn’t work from my local session. Thanks